# Why is voltage essential in circuits?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

I understand what voltage is, but why is it necessary for an electric circuit to function? Why can't current flow without a voltage?

Comment: Current can flow without voltage, but you need superconductors for that and even then there will be an induction term when the current changes.

Answer (score 1):

Point particles as the electrons (which are the charge carriers) move according to Newton's law $\textbf{F}=q\textbf{E}=m\textbf{a}$. Whenever an electric field is present it generates a difference of potential between two points $A$ and $B$ given by its differential form calculated between the two points
$$
V_A - V_B = \int_A^B \textbf{E}\cdot d\textbf{s}.
$$
In the simple case where the electric field is parallel to the displacement and constant this gives you back $V_A - V_B = E\,\Delta s$. Replacing into the Newton's law yields back 
$$
m\textbf{a}=q\,\frac{V_A - V_B}{\Delta s}
$$
ergo no potential difference would mean no acceleration. Roughly speaking for electrons to move they need an electric field, and an electric field generates a difference of potential between two points.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a difference in electrical potential in a circuit. You can compare this to a ball sitting at the top of a hill - as it rolls downwards, it moves through a difference in gravitational potential. Because the ball has lower potential at the bottom of the hill, it will roll there spontaneously. The ball will never roll up the hill by itself, increasing its potential energy. Nor will it spontaneously roll across level ground, where there is no potential difference to drive it. The voltage in a circuit is what causes the electrons to move through the circuit, across the gap in potential. With no voltage, there's no potential difference, meaning the electrons won't flow (i.e. electricity).